# "my mother was my powerhouse" and "father a school of thoughts"

Tags: style, metaphors, rhetoric

I remember:

> In a palace of formations, my mother was my powerhouse and father a school of thoughts.

Is this style of writing correct? What can be better choice for the same sentence, grammatically?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "school of thoughts"? is this a literal translation of an idiom in your native language? A **school of thought** usually means a lot of people have agreed on a particular issue or idea and have adopted it as their own. I'm not sure if anyone can embody a [***school of thought***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/school-of-thought) (singular), without mentioning what it was.

Comment: By the way, I like the imagery the sentence evokes.

Comment: Going along with the "palace" metaphor, I would say, "My mother was my bedrock" to symbolize the foundation of my palace.

Comment: And perhaps, "My father was my (ivory) tower." But note that "ivory tower" may have negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of metaphors is correct and used often.

> My mother is my powerhouse.

is understandable and correct, however the same notion is usually expressed as

> My mother is my strength.

Your second phrase

> father a school of thought *(singular)*

has the meaning one has created a school of thought

it is along the same lines of the idiom

> every great idea has a thousand fathers.

meaning if there is a great idea, many people will want to claim credit for it.